# Chrome extension manifest 2 and 1, compatibility

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, chromium

I have an extension that I recently upgraded to manifest version 2. To do this I removed the `background_page` property in the manifest file and replaced it with `background: {page: "background.html"}`. This works and everything is fine. Turns out, however, that there are browsers and people out there with old versions of Chrome, or versions of Rockmelt and other Chromium-based browsers that don't support the `background`-property, or the `manifest_version: 2` yet.

A simple solution would be to just add the `background_page: "background.html"`-property to the manifest file, in addition to the `background`-property. This gives the warning in `chrome://extension` developer mode:

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
     'background_page' requires manifest version of 1 or lower.
```

My question is: can having both have any negative impact? For example, what will happen when `background_page` is deprecated? Will my users see any warnings? Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even thought having undocumented, deprecated or experimental attributes in `manifest.json` gives warnings, these warnings are only visible with "Developer mode" active. They don't affect end-user. In my option you are perfectly fine keeping `background-page:` in your manifest.

You can also consider using [minimum_chrome_version](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#minimum_chrome_version) to block users with older browsers from downloading your latest update. It's a bit too late for that (since your `manifest_vesion: 2` update is published) but you can do a small trick here. Downgrade to `manifest_version: 1`, wait for everyone to download downgraded version and, yet again, push update with `manifest_version: 2` this time adding `minimum_chrome_version: 18`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the [`manifest_version`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html) attribute. It's not your personal revision of the manifest file which you have to increase on every change, it's a format specifier. So there's no need for the downgrade-upgrade trick.

Comment: @Psycho I'm aware of what `manifest_version` is for. The issue here was that OP pushed a new version of extension using manifest v2 while , back then, a lot of browsers still haven't recognized it (Chrome/Chromium version < 18). So my advice was to publish new version of his extension using old manifest v1 and, after a while, publish once again with manifest v2, this time adding `minimum_chrome_version` parameter. This way, old browsers won't upgrade to the new (and unsupported) version of the extension.

Comment: I see, didn't think Chrome could update extensions without checking the manifest version.

Answer (score 44):

You should replace "background_page" with "background".

Like:

```
"background": "background.html"
```

Rather than:

```
"background": {"page": "background.html"}
```

Comment: Yes, I have that. The question was if having both would negatively affect the extension.